# Transfer Ubuntu to new, smaller disk with different partition number

Tags: boot, partitioning, boot-repair, transfer

I've read a few questions and answers, and most answer are to use `dd` to copy the disk to the new disk, which is always larger.  I'm trying to move only a single partition on a 1TB disk, to a 250GB SSD.

My current setup:

```
sda SSD, GRUB INSTALLED HERE
--sda1 Windows 10 recovery
--sda2 Windows 10 OS ~240 GB

sdb Mechanical HDD, 1TB
--sdb1 Ubuntu 16.04 ~110 GB
--sdb2 NTFS Storage ~650 GB
--sdb3 EXT4 ~16GB (used for testing and backups)
--sdb4 Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 ~120GB
--sdb5 SWAP
```

My new SSD is also 240GB and I got an external case to transfer the OS.  I'm going to swap the 1TB for the SSD, which is smaller, but I only want sdb4 moved.  It will look like this:

```
sdb NEW SSD
--sdb1 Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 ~120GB
--sdb2 Swap ~8GB
--sdb3 NTFS Storage ~112GB
```

The new sdb3 NTFS will be an empty new partition, I don't want to copy it from the 1TB.

To do the transfer, I'll remove my 1TB from my laptop, put in the SSD in its place, and put the 1TB in a external USB case to access it.  I'll boot from a LiveUSB, and then, what?

From what I've read, I can't just do `dd` from the 1TB to the SSD because it's smaller, and I don't want to copy the entire disk, I only want sdb4 copied over.  Will it copy it over to the new disk as sdb1 or still sdb4?

After I figure out how this is done, I should be able to mount the new SSD and chroot into it to run `update-grub` right?

Since the partitions use UUID's, is the new SSD's copied Linux partition going to have a new UUID?  Is this going to cause problems booting/running if it has a new UUID?  On the other hand, if the UUID is also copied over, will this cause problems by having 2 identical UUID's present when I have the USB plugged in?  I would rather not delete sdb4 from the 1TB and will keep it as a backup.  I will also continue to use the 1TB via USB for storage.

Lastly, obviously I'll have to edit my `/etc/fstab`.

Sorry for all the question, but everything I read from using dd, to gparted and other software all are unclear and do things differently.  And it's unclear if the OS will have problems when its partition identifier has changed (sdb1/4 or new UUID).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I took the plunge since nobody answered and decided to give it a shot, and it worked, in the end.  Here's what I did;

I plugged my new SSD in via USB.
Opened gparted and went to my 1TB, right-clicked the Ubuntu install I wanted to copy, and clicked on "Copy".  Went to the new SSD, right-clicked the empty drive and "Paste".  It took a while but it copied over the entire partition and preserved the UUID.  I did the same thing for the swap partition so that the new one would have the same UUID and I wouldn't even have to make any changes in my `/etc/fstab` since it uses UUIDs.  I then created a blank NTFS partition that I can share between Ubuntu and Windows.

Once that was done I physically swapped the new SSD and the 1TB drive.  Upon booting, I got a device doesn't exist error.

I booted into a LiveUSB and selected "Try Ubuntu".

Then I opened a terminal and typed out this:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

With `sdb1` being the new partition that I copied over from my old 1TB, and `sda` is my Windows drive, which always had grub installed on it.

Running the `grub-install` command above detected Ubuntu's new home on the SSD, and also detected Windows 10.  I didn't even have to do an `update-grub` command.

I rebooted the laptop and grub came up with my 2 options of Ubuntu Gnome or Windows 10, and both options work great!

My 1TB is now in the USB case that I used for the SSD originally, just to copy the partition.  It will be used now for long-term storage.  I prefer the speed over the size.

Side note; Running Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 on the SSD is blazing fast and boots in about 5 seconds to desktop.  Suffice to say I'm quite happy!